# Apache Directory studio ldap bind from php

Tags: apache, ldap

I am new to Apache Directory Studio and ldap. I am running a ldap server from Apache Directory studio. I have a user in ldap and i am trying to bind to the uid from a php script.Not sure where i am going wrong.

I am using username as `"uid=admin,ou=user"`
password as `"secret"`

I also tried username as `"uid=arone_a,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com"`
and password as `"password"`

Password attribute was set manually and `arone_a` is the user uid.

I am trying to write a php script which can pull all users in the ldap server.

Thanks in advance.

My PHP script is:

```
$ldaphost = "localhost"; 

$ldapport = 10389;                

$ldaprdn='uid=admin,ou=system';

$ldappass='secret';

$ldapconn = ldap_connect($ldaphost, $ldapport)
          or die("Could not connect to $ldaphost");

if($ldapconn)
{

       $ldapbind=ldap_bind($ldapconn,$ldaprdn,$ldappass);


       if($ldapbind)
       {

                echo "success";
       }
       else
       {

                echo "not success";
       }
}
```

Connection goes through but bind is not going through.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue and the problem was that I added to the `userPassword` attribute an additional param specifying the language, resulting in `userPassword;lang-ca-ES` (the wizard shows a form to add it).

That provoked that using Apache Directory Studio the "Verify" was working good, but it failed in the "Bind" check (you can do both in the password editor, double clicking the `userPassword` attribute.

I finally left `userPassword` without additional attributes and it binded perfectly :)

Comment: And in php code be sure to take into account what Terry points, using the right and full DN.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the ldap set option, it worked for me

```
<?php 

$ldaphost = "localhost"; 

$ldapport = 10389;                

$ldaprdn='uid=admin,ou=system';

$ldappass='secret';

$ldapconn = ldap_connect($ldaphost, $ldapport)
          or die("Could not connect to $ldaphost");

if($ldapconn) {
    ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

       $ldapbind=ldap_bind($ldapconn,$ldaprdn,$ldappass);

       if($ldapbind) {
                echo "success";
                
       } else {
                echo "not success";

       }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple BIND request requires the DN, not the RDN. Should your BIND DN be something like `uid=admin,ou=system,dc=example,dc=com`?

#### see also

- [LDAP: Authentication best practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/authentication-best-practices.html)
- [LDAP: Programming practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-programming-practices.html)

Comment: I tried giving username as 'uid=admin,ou=system,dc=example,dc=com' with password 'secret'.I still could not bind. From the Apache Directory Studio, I could check connection properties and was able to bind with the username and password. But when i try to do the same from a PHP script I could not. Do i have to change any settings? I am running PHP through MAMP.